# What would speed up the Tor network the most: 500Mbits server or 5 x 100Mbits servers?

Tags: relays, exit-relays

What would speed up the Tor network the most: 500Mbits exit relay server or 5 x 100Mbits exit relay servers?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the 5 x 100Mbits exit relay servers, which would offer more circuits for a great bandwidth